# Two Different Catkin Workspaces

Tags: catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two weeks ago, I created a catkin workspace, and then some folders were deleted by my little brother. After he deleted some folders in the computer, I could not find my workspace, and created another workspace. When I started to work in second workspace, I found my first workspace, which is assumed to be deleted. Right now, I have two catkin workspaces, and I want to delete second one.

As far as I know, I can delete a workspace by using the command "catkin clean" in that workspace. I used it, and  the command deleted devel and build folders. However, the folder "src" still remains with CMakeList.txt file. I deleted them manually, meaning transfer them to recycle bin.

Actually, I am very new to ROS system; hence, I do not know there is anything that I have to do in order to clean a workspace.

Is it done, is that workspace completely deleted from the computer ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304530/two-different-catkin-workspaces/) by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2018-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### **TL;DR**

You can delete your old catkin workspace folder and remove possible references for its previous `devel/setup.bash`.

### **Informational answer**

The command `catkin clean` only clean the files generated by catkin build.

A catkin workspace is a folder. It contains a `src` folder with some ROS packages inside. There can exist multiple workspaces with different names, but only one is usually activated.

To activate a workspace, you need to init and build  it first, generating the folders `devel` and `build`.  Then, you need to source the `setup.bash`.

If you want to know which workspace is activated at the moment, you can check the first folder from command

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

You can find examples of workflow at [catkin-tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html) website. It seems complicated at first, but soon you will get the hang of it ;)

Cheers,

---

Originally posted by [Bruno Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/37834/bruno-lima/) with karma: 81 on 2018-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on 2018-10-01**:
At first, I appreciate your answer. Thank you so much. I used the command "echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, and terminal shows the directory opt/ros/indigo. I suppose that any workspace is not activated right now. Is the command below correct to activate a workspace ? (source devel/setup.bash)

**Comment by [Bruno Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/37834/bruno-lima/) on 2018-10-01**:
Yes, but you need to use the full path when referring to devel/setup.bash. In my case, the command is:
source /home/bruno/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
You need to source it once for each new opened terminal. Or put it at your ~/.bashrc and every terminal will start with your workspace activated.

**Comment by [Bruno Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/37834/bruno-lima/) on 2018-10-01**:
I strongly recommend you to give a look at the link I gave you, which is the Catkin-tools Quickstart. It is a good reading about Catkin workflow. There is also a Cheat Sheet avaliable for quick checks.

**Comment by [mikeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/65617/mikeo/) on 2020-12-14**:
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

/home/package_ws/src:/home/tango_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share

I have two workspaces here, i'm running from tango_ws, but there is a launch file which launch a package from the package_ws, does this mean two workspaces are activated here?